# Detectron2: Inference using pre-trained model - The checkpoint state_dict contains keys that are not used by the model: pixel_mean pixel_std

Tags: python, detectron

I m trying to do inference on a pre-trained model (centermask2) with Detectron2. The inference results are not great, and I get this message below -

```
The checkpoint state_dict contains keys that are not used by the model:
  pixel_mean
  pixel_std
```

I've also tried explicitly setting the pixel_mean and pixel_std value in the code:

```
cfg.MODEL.PIXEL_STD = [3.6, 3.6, 3.6]
cfg.MODEL.PIXEL_MEAN = [117.1313121, 117.1313121, 117.1313121]
```

But I also keep getting this message.

How do I fix this - so that my mode uses these keys?

Thank you!

Comment: please provide your code, it is not clear so far what's causing your problem